# How to make different durations with useSpring?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I want my component to have an animation that if my mouse enter,it will be fully displayed in 0.3s,and if my mouse leave,it will disappear in 0.1s.But useSpring can just define one duration just like the code below,which cause that the component will be displayed and disappear all in 0.3s.How can I define different duration for from->to and to->from?Thanks for anyone who can help.

```
const animationStyle = useSpring({
bottom: show ? 0 : -71,
from: {
  bottom: -71
},
config: { duration: 300 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
import import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { animated, useSpring } from '@react-spring/web';

const SuspendedComponent: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [isMouseEnter, setMouseEnter] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const _style = useSpring({
        bottom: isMouseEnter ? 0 : -71,
        from: {
            bottom: -71,
        },
        config: { duration: 300 },
    });

    function onMouseHandler(isEnter: boolean) {
        setMouseEnter(isEnter);
    }

    return (
        <div
            style={{ display: 'block', width: '100px', height: '100px' }}
            onMouseEnter={() => onMouseHandler(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => onMouseHandler(false)}
        >
            {isMouseEnter && <animated.div style={_style}>{children}</animated.div>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default SuspendedComponent;
```

You can control `animated.div` element display by onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave event.